# Is there a way to control where a Text widget overflow occurs (how many lines)?

Tags: flutter

Right now it seems like if I set the overflow to TextOverflow.ellipsis it cuts off the text at the end of the first line.  I want the text to be able to wrap to and fill a second line but no farther.  If the content exceeds the length of the second line, then I'd like it to display ellipsis.

Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Worst case scenario, I can write a function to manually check and amend the text before I pass it to the widget, I suppose, but checking to see if there's a Flutter way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Jan 3, 2017, we do not currently provide a Widget which supports multi-line overflow effects, however we do have an issue on file requesting this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4202